# Problems using class library on production machine

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, vs-web-site-project

I have a class library with various namespaces created using VB.NET.

Example Class:

```
Namespace XYZ
    Public NotInheritable Class Class1
        Shared Function One() As List(Of String)
        End Function

        Shared Sub Two()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

There are several of these inside of a ClassLibrary.dll that is referenced in the ASP.NET Web Forms Web Site.

When I use this on the development machine, it works fine.  However, when I try to call a page on the production machine that uses any code referenced it doesn't work.

My apologies, I don't have exact error messages, but they are basically:

1. Class1 has not been declared.
2. Namespace XYZ doesn't contain any Public members (or something along those line).

I have done some searching and haven't had any luck.

This code works when I test it using desktop applications and the aspx page running on the development machine's IIS.

I have tried moving the code to a module which didn't work.  I have tried creating a new class file directly in the site and re-writing the code which didn't work.

When I place the code directly in the aspx.vb page, it doesn't generate the Compilation Error, but the DropDownLists still do not populate.

Example Code to Populate DropDownLists:

```
ddl_One.DataSource = Class1.GetEmployeeNames()
ddl_One.DataBind()
```

Edit (more information):

Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 11.0.50938.18408
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

error BC30002: Type 'CapabilitiesForm' is not defined.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

Comment: Is this a web site, or a web application project?

Comment: It's important to specify that, perhaps by using the [tag:web-site-project] tag. They're quite different from anything else.

Comment: I mentioned it in my original post "There are several of these inside of a ClassLibrary.dll that is referenced in the ASP.NET Web Forms Web Site."  A tag would have been nice too though.  Ty

Comment: The term "web site" needs to be explicitly disambiguated. Many people using a web application project still refer to it as a web site, at least part of the time.

Comment: That was my mistake.  I thought stating it was an "ASP.NET Web Forms Web Site" would remove the ambuiguity.  Thanks for adding a tag and the clarification.

Comment: Yeah, "web site project" would make it clear enough to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with an IIS setting related to Application Pool.

I apologize I do not have a detailed solution, but it was through troubleshooting another issue that this one was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile then changed it to .Net Framework 4.0 and check if the `Microsoft .NET Framework 4` on the production machine. maybe only the `Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client profile` is installed?

Also please check if the imported DLL is checked in Project properties => References => Imported namespaces

Comment: I think you may be on to something with the .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile.  When they were setting up the IIS box I remember him commenting on not sure which one to chose.  I will have him check it out tomorrow.  I do know that I did add the reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, the versions were the same on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Re Compile the website and then publish. Sometimes it does the trick.

Comment: I'm still waiting on an update on whether publish worked or not.  I know I have compiled the site several times and had no luck.